# Подскажите плагин Jquery - всплывающие подсказки над элементом

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста плагин Jquery - всплывающие подсказки над элементом, чтобы можно было настраивать для разных контейнеров HTML, скажем при наведении на IMG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JQuery UI Tooltip|](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: Подошел - только вот проблематично выставить подсказку сверху по центру над объектом

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте https://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/ это css но тем и лучше